# What is the convenience method to compare two NSNumbers with float values using limited precision?

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, comparison, precision, convenience-methods

What is the Objective-C convenience method for comparing a couple of NSNumbers with float values to see if they are roughly equivalent (two decimal places of precision is fine)?

I would use something other than floats if there was an option that did not change the number around randomly. But anyway I'm already using floats so... .

I imagine there must be something like:

[myNumber isEqualTo:myOtherNumber withPrecision:2];

But actually, amazingly I can't find such a convenience method. What am I missing here?

Would it help to cast the two numbers to NSDecimal or something?

Comment: Pseudo-code version looks like this: `( abs(num1 - num2) < 0.01 )`.  This evaluates to true if the difference between them is less than one-onehundredth (which is 2 decimal points of precision), and false otherwise.

Comment: There is no convenience method because there is no general rule for comparing floating point numbers with a tolerance. The proper comparison is application-dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return (fabs([myNumber doubleValue] - [myOtherNumber doubleValue]) < 0.01);
```

My objective-c is a little rusty, but putting this in a method that accepts to NSNumbers and returns a bool should work.

Comment: I'm aware of this method, but I was looking for a proper convenience method. I guess one doesn't exist.

Comment: Well I guess I have to live with this